# Expérimenter dans le sens de "vivre une expérience"

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot

Je reçois aujourd'hui 2 e-mails de 2 commerçants différents suite à des commandes en ligne. Ils veulent en savoir plus quant à mon expérience avec la commande sur leur site. Le sujet de ces emails est:

> Comment avez-vous expérimenté [nom du service] ?

> Comment s'est passée votre expérience avec [nom du service] ?

Je ne peux m'empêcher de trouver la première formulation un peu étrange; pour moi "expérimenter" sonne faux dans ce contexte. Je rencontre souvent cela sur les sites (belges) que je fréquente, les traductions sont parfois faites un peu maladroitement depuis le néerlandais.

Je pense que quoi qu'il en soit la seconde formulation "passe" beaucoup mieux, mais ma question est: **l'emploi du verbe "expérimenter" dans ce contexte est-il correct ou non ?**

Comment: Correct selon qui, j'ai envie de demander.

Answer (score 1):

- L'emploi du verbe "expérimenter" dans ce contexte est-il correct ou non ?

Il est grammaticalement correct mais le choix de ce verbe, sans entraîner de contresens total, est indubitablement du à l'influence de l'anglais, comme d'ailleurs l'utilisation d'*experience* dans la deuxième formulation. Utiliser *expérimenter* choque un peu plus que *votre expérience* car contrairement à l'anglais, le français n'a pas de verbe *expériencer* alors que l'anglais distingue d'une part *an experiment/to experiment* et d'autre part *an experience/to experience*. L'introduction du verbe *expériencer* est parfois évoquée, par exemple dans [cet article](https://www.cairn.info/revue-critique-2012-12-page-1012.htm) de Stéphane Madelrieux dans la revue Critique, 2012 où l'on peut lire:

> Nous voudrions profiter de la traduction de ce texte pour introduire en français le verbe « expériencer », avec les dérivés « expériençable » et « expérientiel ». Il y a des raisons linguistiques : il est souvent très lourd et parfois impossible, notamment pour le participe passé, de traduire par « faire l’expérience de ». Il y a des raisons philosophiques : « expériencer » traduit mieux l’immédiateté de l’expérience dont parle Dewey. Il ne présuppose pas un sujet et un objet bien définis de l’expérience, thèse essentielle de Dewey, contrairement au français qui restitue un sujet grammatical même neutre (les choses « dont on fait l’expérience ») ou semble invoquer un tiers entre l’individu et les choses (« qui sont l’objet d’une expérience »). Il indique enfin un nouveau sens du concept, qui ne se confond ni avec le sens empirique de l’Antiquité (le savoir-faire pratique habituel), ni avec le sens empiriste de l’âge classique (le donné des sens passivement reçu), ni avec le sens expérimental des sciences modernes (la mise à l’épreuve active et contrôlée d’une hypothèse), mais qui les intègre comme des phases d’un processus global de transaction vécue entre un organisme et son environnement.

Il y a quelques décennies, je n'aurais probablement pas compris ce que la première question cherchait me demander, ne voyant pas où pouvait se situer une démarche de recherche expérimentale dans un processus d'achat, et aurait trouvé la deuxième question très bizarre, ne vivant simplement pas ce processus d'achat comme une *expérience*.

Aujourd'hui, on rencontre de plus en plus d'expressions comme *améliorer l'expérience utilisateur* sous l'influence claire de l'anglais *user experience* et ce sens élargi d'*expérience* et peut-être aussi celui d'*expérimenter* rentreront dans l'usage courant.

On ne peut pas reprocher à *expérience/expérimenter* d'introduire du vocabulaire anglais dans notre langue puisqu'ils sont déjà tout à fait français.

Answer (score 0):

L'objet d'un courriel devrait *refléter* le contenu du message, donc c'est inadapté. De surcroît, la phrase ne remplie pas sa fonction. Comment répondre à une question aussi abstruse ?

Comment: Il s'agit du sujet d'un e-mail sous la forme d'une question. Les véritables questions sont mieux posées...

Answer (score -3):

Le verbe « expérimenter » dans la première phrase est très probablement un très récent complément de l'usage lui aussi récent du mot « expérience », qui apparemment nous vient du monde commercial de l'informatique américain, non pas que le mot n'existe pas en français mais du seul fait que l'usage français ne l'a jamais étendu  aussi bas dans le parler de tous les jours, ou pour mieux dire, ne l'a pas vulgarisé.

« Expérimenter » a deux sens d'après le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exp%C3%A9rimenter), les deux sens « A » en relation avec les *expériences vécues*, puisque évidemment il faut exclure les sens « B » concernant les *expériences provoquées*.

> A.− [Expérimenter renvoie à une expérience vécue]
> 1.**Éprouver, apprendre, découvrir par une expérience personnelle**  :
> 1/ Ainsi j'expérimentais sans cesse à travers elle combien le monde visuel diffère du monde des sons et à quel point toute comparaison que l'on cherche à tirer de l'un pour l'autre est boiteuse. Gide, Symph. pastor.,1919, p. 894.
> − Absolument :
> 2/ La tradition vous répugne et le neuf (...). Le neuf est tout de suite à l'école. De cette minute il cesse de l'être. Vous le classez, vous l'étiquetez et, comme vous n'admettez pas qu'un artiste expérimente, vous exigez de lui qu'il se répète. Cocteau, Lettre Amér.,1949, p. 16.
> 2. **Ressentir brutalement une sensation, un sentiment qui pourrait à l'avenir servir de leçon.** Il expérimenta là une de ses pires épreuves (Malègue, Augustin,t. 2, 1933, p. 411).

On doit pouvoir se convaincre aisément que de ces deux définitions, celle que l'on peut appliquer dans le cas présent d'une interaction commerciale de routine  n'est que la première puisque l'on ne peut pas arbitrairement supposer qu'il s'agirait de *sensation brutale*, et serait-il question d'une telle sensation à la découverte que l'on a été roulé et que l'on en est pour son argent, par exemple, il n'y a aucun escroc qui pousserait la perversion jusqu'à aller s'enquérir auprès de sa victime de l'intensité du choc créé.

Donc, ces commerçants sont curieux de savoir comment vous avez été affecté par cette interaction dans le sens d'avoir eu des sentiments particuliers, d'avoir appris des choses nouvelles, d'avoir fait des découvertes, tout cela dans le cadre de cette interaction.
À mon avis, il n'y a pas dans ce vocabulaire de bien grande erreur d'identification de concept mais seulement un glissement de l'ensemble habituel des concepts susceptibles d'être appréhendés par ce vocabulaire vers un ensemble de même nature sauf que les éléments de celui-ci seraient beaucoup moins intellectuels. C'est ce qui détonne, encore à mon avis, dans l'utilisation du mot « expérimenter » en relation avec les états d'esprit associés aux formalités et actes qu'implique un simple achat. Là où en d'autres temps on aurait simplement demandé au client ce qu'il pensait du service, on insiste maintenant pour connaitre ses réactions intimes concernant le service, ses pensées plus réfléchies, et cela semble excessif.

En ce qui concerne la  seconde phrase il semble que l'usage du verbe « se passer » soit trop fort; il n'est question dans une opération d'achat ni d'épreuve, ni de situation offrant le moindre danger ou la perspective d'un bien grand inconnu, ni d'obstacle difficiles à surmonter – c'est surtout dans ces cas-là que l'on demande comment ça s'est passé –, et après tout  ce n'est souvent qu'un acte de routine que beaucoup trouvent ennuyeux et un gaspillage de temps; on a tellement peu d'intérêt de nos jours pour l'expérience de l'achat in situ que l'on fait un maximum d'achats par télécommunication.
Cela mis à part, ma critique pour le mot « expérience » est la même que pour le mot précédent, qui s'y rapporte directement.

Comment: Google est sans appel: Aucun résultat trouvé pour "achats par télécommunication".

Comment: @jlliagre Bien sûr, une construction peut ne pas avoir été utilisée mais celle-ci est du type obtenu selon le principe de compositionalité ; c'est comme par exemple « message par télépathie » (signification déduite à partir du sens des mots et des relations). En d'autre termes, ce sont des unités du langage auto-définies. Comme « achat par télécommunication » est une construction de ce type et un autre moyen de dire la même chose je l'ai retenu. « En ligne », n'est pas autre chose que « par télécommunication », « par internet » ; on aurait  pu dire « achat par internet », il me semble. (1/2)

Comment: @jlliagre compositionalité:https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principe_de_compositionnalit%C3%A9

Comment: Dommage. Pour une fois que j'étais assez d'accord avec ta réponse, ton entêtement me conduit à remplacer un +1 par un -1...

Comment: @jlliagre Est-ce à dire que vous ne reconnaissez pas ce principe ou bien qu'il n'est pas, ou mal appliqué dans la construction en question ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas de problème avec ce principe qui enfonce les portes ouvertes. Alors que les formes *achats par téléphone*, *achats par Internet*, *achats par ordinateur* sont englobées dans la formule consacrée *achats en ligne*, le choix de *télécommunication* n'a pas ici de justification. On peut dire, *je lui ai répondu par courrier, par téléphone, par mail, pas sms, de vive voix, par lettre recommandée, voire par transmission de pensée* mais *je lui ai répondu par télécommunication* est abracadabrantesque.